# Using inject with an array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes, each with a key `lol` which has an integer value. I'd like to sum the values, inject always worked but now I get an exception:

```
array = [{lol: 1}, {lol: 2}]
array.inject {|memo, (key, value)| memo + value} =>
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for {:lol=>1}:Hash
from (irb):26:in `block in irb_binding'
from (irb):26:in `each'
from (irb):26:in `inject'
from (irb):26
```

Por que?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't specify an argument to `inject`, the value for the memo object for the first iteration is the first element of the enumerable, an hash in this case. So you just have to pass `0` as the argument to `inject`:

```
array = [{lol: 1}, {lol: 2}]
array.inject(0) { |sum, h| sum + h[:lol] }
# => 3
```

Comment: That was my first try but without initialization, so I searched for a key/value solution which also didn't work. Dead simple thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can just get all the hash values with `flat_map(&:values)`, then use `inject(:+)` to sum them.

```
[{lol: 1}, {lol: 2}].flat_map(&:values).inject(:+)
```

The reason your approach doesn't work is that inject is going to yield each hash to the block, rather than each key/value pair of each hash in the array. If you wanted to keep your solution, you'd want something like:

```
array.map {|hash| hash.inject(0) {|memo, (key, value)| memo + value } }.inject(:+)
```

Comment: +1, but I'd write the second snippet like this: `array.inject(0) {|memo, h| memo + h[:lol] }`. Also `inject(0, :+)` for the first. Althouth the OP seems to want only the "lol" key, so: `[{lol: 1}, {lol: 2}].map { |h| h[:lol] }.inject(0, :+)`

Comment: Assuming that `:lol` is the only key whose value you care about, absolutely.

Comment: A little bit longer than the accepted answer, but I learned something new, +1.

Answer (score 5):

From .inject [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

> If you do not explicitly specify an initial value for memo, then the first element of collection is used as the initial value of memo.

```
array.inject {|memo, (key, value)| memo + value}
```

The value for memo is a hash instead of a number.

Correct it as

```
array.inject(0) {|memo, hash| memo + hash[:lol]} # => 3
```